# How can I make same orientation for bones in edit and pose modes?

Tags: bones, axis, transform-orientation

How could I rotate axes in pose mode to align them with axes in edit mode?

When I did armature for a model, I ended up having bones with local space axes pointing in different directions in edit mode at compared to pose mode. Have a look at the screenshot below please.
[image]

I suspect this may have happened because I inaccurately applied a position in pose mode as Rest Pose.
But now I'm experiencing issues during animation with local axes when I export it to Unreal engine.

Looks likes, edit mode axis positions is correct because it matches global axes. I would like to make them point in the same direction.

**UPD** The file with armature is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z1x5DKVVjRK3SzPkSMHeFob0xiCBnI0_/view?usp=drive_link

**UPD2** As @moonboots said in the comments below, bone in Edit mode displays Armature orientation. In Pose pose, the orientation of a particular bone is displayed. It doesn't seem to be an issues here anymore. As to my problem with animation in Unreal Engine. I've figured out it is not big issue and decided to leave it as is. I'm doing animation sequences with 2 ways in the Unreal: manually with mouse or adding coordinates with Python. I've found out I can switch to World space(or set with Python to world space) and axes are looking straight for every control in that case.

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots please see my first post. I've updated it

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything abnormal here, if you are in Edit mode you see the armature orientation, if you are in Pose mode you see the bone local orientation

Comment: If it is armature orientation in Edit mode, then I think I misinterpretted something. In that case it is good and I need to think how to align control rigs in Unreal instead of Blender... Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Note that you can display the bone orientation in the Data panel > Viewport Display > Axes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in *Edit* mode is the armature's axis, not the bone axis. In *Pose* mode you'll see the bone axis, but you can also display it with the *Data panel > Viewport Display > Axes* option:

[image]

Comment: Yep, I think everything is oriented naturally. I thought edit mode displays local axes of bones not armature. It confused me. I will mark this answer as correct one.